# Rails validation error message is not showing and is giving undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

After Googling and searching on stackoverflow. Still can't find a solution to my problem. My `Post` model validation error message is not showing and is giving undefined method error.

I have a `Post` model that has some validations ( `presence, length` ) and some validation messages. When I clicked Create `Post` without typing the content, instead showing the validation messages, it gives me an `undefined method error`. But when the validations are met, the post is created. Which means the `NoMethodError` is actually not there, if the method is not defined in my `Post` Controller, how can the post be created?

Please see below my`post.rb` , `_form.html.erb`, `_error_messages.html.erb`,`NoMethodError Page`

### post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :question

validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :question_id, presence: true

validates :content, :presence => { :message => "Content is required" }, length: { 
        minimum: 100,
        maximum: 500,
        tokenizer: lambda { |str| str.scan(/\w+/) },
        too_short: "must have at least %{count} words",
        too_long: "must have at most %{count} words",  
    }

    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

end
```

### _form.html.erb

```
<%= @question.title %>

<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, :value => @question.id %><br>
  </div> 

  <div>
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>


  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### _error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### NoMethodError Page

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#create
undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #27):

25
26  def create
27  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
28
29
30  respond_to do |format|


Rails.root: /Users/jim/project/test
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:27:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"cakWqDu67ZyrJ6KTW8GlexoLrCFgyQnnRljT6wksGc4=",
 "post"=>{"question_id"=>"1",
 "content"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Post"}
```

### NoMethodError 2

```
NoMethodError in Posts#create

Showing /Users/jim/project/test/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #2):

1
2  <%= @question.title %>
3  <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
4
5



Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /Users/jim/project/test
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_posts__form_html_erb___2518287212872033894_2203911920'
app/views/posts/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_posts_new_html_erb___3716195397608425729_2203949420'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:30:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"fjUYhjW24sFHL/99lnYGjpsLQVa4En2UlNtPvY5imi0=",
 "post"=>{"question_id"=>"1",
 "content"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Post"}
```

Comment: please post the controller code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Bachan Smruty found the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `create` action, you need to fetch the `@question`. As per your code, when any error comes, application renders the "new.html.erb" page in the `create` action.

```
def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      #YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    else
      @question = Question.where(id: params[:post][:question_id]).first
      render 'new'
end
```

Comment: Oh I see, it works but I don't understand this line `@question = Question.where(id: params[:post][:question_id]).first` , is it calling the first Question? Can you explain it to me? Thanks

Comment: `@question = Question.where(id: params[:post][:question_id]).first` it just fetch the question is having the id is equal to question_id. But the where statement returns the result as an array. And for this result, the array contains a single element. So, we are adding .first to the array to get that activerecord Question object.

Comment: Yeah, is it calling the first Question ?  Why `params[:post][:question_id]` ?

Comment: No it is not calling the first question. params[:post][:question_id] carries the value, that you have added in the hidden_field of your form. And the query is like "Select * from questions where question_id=3" (lets say params[:post][:question_id] = 3). And this results an array where it returns all the records from questions which is having id is 3. In this case it should return a single record as id is unique. So we need to take the first element of that array to get the question object. You can take Question.find params[:post][:question_id] instead of that as well.

Comment: But if in the find statement, if it doesn't find any record, it throws an error while using `where`, it returns an blank array.

Comment: Hi Bachan, do you know why this line `@question = Question.where(id: params[:post][:question_id]).first` is giving me this error `no implicit conversion of Question into String` ?

Comment: Is this the error for that line? If yes, then try with the following code Question.find_by_id(params[:post][:question_id])

Comment: I'm not sure if it's that line or not, I have tried the code but it's still the same. Btw, I have open another question base on this, please check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297551/rails-4-form-no-implicit-conversion-of-model-into-string

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is totally different here, it says that `current_user` is nil, are you sure that `current_user` is initialized?
Maybe you should have a before_filter that handles the "no current_user" case.

Comment: yeah, I'm using Devise's current_user, but when the validations are met, the post is created. And now it's giving me another `NoMethodError`, I have added in my post.