# Rails 4 form - no implicit conversion of Model into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After adding a helper method and edit my form, I'm getting this error

```
TypeError in Posts#create

Showing /Users/jim/project/test/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

no implicit conversion of Question into String

Extracted source (around line #2):

1
2      <%= show_random(@question)[:title] %>
3

app/helpers/questions_helper.rb:4:in `show_random'
app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_posts__form_html_erb___4147312638633006209_2202637820'
app/views/posts/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_posts_new_html_erb___3518261482060642021_2203102520'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:33:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"MK1wiBKc8MqXsKPtvbgJWaBNAaZ7kHm7RDVC8ZYRMNc=",
 "post"=>{"question_id"=>"1",
 "content"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Post"}
```

But this error won't appear if the validations of `Post` model are met. So I'm guessing (not sure) there's something wrong with my `if else statement` in my `create` action of my `Posts controller` but I don't know how to fix it.

### questions_helper.rb

```
module QuestionsHelper

    def show_random(random)
        JSON.parse(random).with_indifferent_access
    end

end
```

### _form.html.erb

```
<%= show_random(@question)[:title] %>

<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, :value => show_random(@question)[:id] %><br>
  </div> 

  <div>
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### posts_controller.erb

```
       def new
         @post = Post.new
         @question = cookies[:question] ||= Question.random  # the random method return a random question serialized record using to_json
       end

       def create
          @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
           if @post.save
             flash[:success] = "Post created successfully!"
           else
             @question = Question.where(id: params[:post][:question_id]).first
           render 'new'
        end
```

Comment: No, the problem is in your helper: 

this is saying that when you are redirecting in your `else` statement in the `create` action, you're passing a `Question` object to you your helper that doesn't know how to convert it into a string (as JSON.parse needs a String object). So, what are you passing in the form of the new (i suppose) action to your helper? that is what you have to pass it to make it work

Comment: first check what data you are getting in `@question` by putting following code on the top of your `_form.html.erb`

`<% raise @question.inspect %>`

Comment: I have added my `new` action of my `Post controller`. Btw, I'm getting
`RuntimeError in Posts#new` when i add `<% raise @question.inspect %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem thanks to @sissy comment.

I should pass `@question = cookies[:question]` instead of `@question = Question.where(id: params[:post][:question_id]).first` in my `create` action of my `posts controller`

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your helper seems suspicious to me -- you're passing a Ruby object and trying to parse it as JSON

I think the @sissy comment is spot on - I think it's an issue with your passing the object at different stages. And considering you're getting the error when you receive errors on `Post.save`, sissy will likely be correct

Further, I'd imagine the fundamental problem would be this:

```
@question ->

     !ruby/object:Question
      attributes:
         -- title: x
         -- created_at: y
         -- updated_at: z
```

If you're parsing JSON, surely this would try to translate `!ruby/object:Question` into an array element, meaning it needs to be a `String` in order for it to work

---

**Fix**

I would fix it by changing the helper to this:

```
#app/helpers/questions_helper.rb
def show_random(post)
   returned_post = Post.random_question(post)
   returned_post.title
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.random_question(post)
        joins(:question).where(#your conditions here)
    end
end
```

You could then use:

```
<%= show_random(@post) %>
```

Comment: I'm using cookies to store the random question and show it in my `Post new.html.erb` , since the cookies is a string so I have to serialized record, and then deserialize using the helper method.