# no implicit conversion of User into String Error only in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

[image]

the above code works when I just run it with ruby
but when I run it in my rails app I get the above error

Comment: Don't post image. Post your code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297551/rails-4-form-no-implicit-conversion-of-model-into-string

Comment: yeah I dont think that is my problem, the above code is independent of my User model, it is just making an API request to a local server.

Comment: Have you try removing `.to_s` and see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it seems like your `@user` object has been set before. Maybe you have set it within some `before_filter`?

The assignment using `||=` only reads the file when `@user` is nil, otherwise, it will ignore the assignment at all.